# Understanding spraklyr library in sql_render() function

Tags: sql, r, dplyr

There is sql_render function which translate dplyr code to SQL,
but I cannot understand the result as SQL code.

```
sc <- spark_connect()
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)
iris <- copy_to(sc, iris, 'iris')
k = iris %>% filter(Sepal_Length > 3) %>% filter(Sepal_Width > 3) %>% 
select(Petal_Length, Petal_Width, Species)

sql_render(k)
```

---

SELECT `Petal_Length` AS `Petal_Length`, `Petal_Width` AS `Petal_Width`, `Species` AS `Species`
FROM (SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *
FROM `iris`
WHERE (`Sepal_Length` > 3.0)) `hezmcfppjh`
WHERE (`Sepal_Width` > 3.0)) `exwivyezte`

---

What is the 'hezmcfppjh' and 'exwivyezte' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hezmcfppjh` and `exwivyezte` are randomly generated query names that dplyr could have used to reference specific parts of the subquery.

In this case, they are unused aliases, but in other operations the alias might be relevant to support: joins, renames, and other operations that require name-disambiguation.